# Conditional Volume Creation in Docker Compose Failing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, volume

I'm facing an issue with my Docker Compose setup, and I'm trying to conditionally create a volume based on the value of the `SRC_VOLUME` environment variable in my `docker-compose.yml` file. However, when I set `SRC_VOLUME=true` in my `.env` file, I encountered the following error message:

```
services.test.volumes.0 type is required
```

Here are my Docker Compose file and `.env` file contents for reference:

**Docker Compose file (`docker-compose.yml`):**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ${SRC_VOLUME:-false}:
        - ./src:/code
```

**.env file contents (`.env`):**

```
# Source Code Volume
SRC_VOLUME=true
```

I expect that when `SRC_VOLUME` is set to `true` in my `.env` file, it should create a volume for the `./src` directory. However, I'm encountering the mentioned error. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it to conditionally create the volume as intended?